# Stripe: Retrieving a paymentIntent in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am trying to get a paymentIntent to look at the charged amount.  My code is:

```
public getIntent($paymentIntentId) 
{
  $stripe = Stripe::setApiKey('____');
  $intent = $stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve($paymentIntentId, []);
  return $intent;
}
```

I keep getting an error logging as `trying to retrieve property of non-object`.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I verified the apiKey is correct and the `$paymentIntentId` is valid.  When I retrieve it via cURL, it works fine so I assume it's an issue with my Laravel code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

From the documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  '[your key]'
);
$stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve(
  '[payment intent id]',
  []
);
```

Or if you want to use `Stripe::setApiKey()`, it doesn't return anything. That is the reason you get this error. To get the intent this way you would have to do:

```
Stripe::setApiKey('___');
$intent = Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve($paymentIntentId)
```